# Can claws mail or sylpheed sync gmail contacts?

Tags: sync, contacts, gmail, sylpheed, claws

I don't mean importing manually, but true syncing?

If not, is there Ubuntu software which syncs gmail contacts separately, and then the above clients sync from that?

Comment: @GData, the solution posted by @hberndt requires login credentials to be entered in the following location: `Preferences` -> `Plugins` -> `GData`.

Answer (score 5):

Claws Mail cannot directly sync gmail contacts.

There is the [GData plugin](http://www.claws-mail.org/plugins.php) which periodically pulls in GMail contacts, and adds them to Claws Mail's address completion list. That means that even though they're still not in the addressbook, they are available in address tab-completion when composing emails, or in filtering based on address book.

It's not a real sync, but it's something that happens automatically in the background, so it might be more comfy than a manual import. Personally, I added an action in Claws Mail to open GMail contacts in a browser, and I just use that instead of the built-in addressbook.

(Full disclosure: I wrote that plugin.)

Comment: Is tjat automatic import supposed to work anymore?  I tried adding action `xdg-open https://www.google.com/contacts/` but I get Input/output erro r, if I run the action from Claws Mail. From terminal it works.

Comment: For GData, The link to open the Google authorization page takes me to the page. After clicking on the acount needed, it gives an error:  "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app

This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."